# How to do odd nested columns with Bootstrap 4 (flex) properly?

Tags: html, sass, bootstrap-4, flexbox

In Bootstrap 4 I haven't found a proper way to deal with nested columns when it doesn't add up with the 12-col system. I've got odd 7-columns and I'd like a nested row of that to have a `.col-5` that takes up the same amount of space as the parent grid would with a 5 columns sized div. [Attached image to better show the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5C1d.jpg)

I had the same problem in Foundation 6 but didn't find a proper solution there either.

Back in the days with [Gumby we had hybrid grids](https://green.gumbyframework.com/docs/grid) for the rescue.

**Here's some code to show what we're trying to do:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5"></div>

  <div class="col-7">
     <div class="row">
       <div class="col-1">
          I want this to be SAME SIZE AS A COL-1 IN PARENT SIZE
        </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        I want this to be SAME SIZE AS A COL-5 IN PARENT SIZE
      </div>
    </div><!-- nested .row (should work as a hybrid 7-col row) -->
  </div><!-- end .col-7 -->

</div><!-- parent .row -->
```

Comment: That's not how columns work. They are always based (in %) of the outer container. You will need to set fixed widths here. Or maybe use display: grid here?

Comment: Thanks for you comment @cloned. As the design shows, the designer wants the nested content to be aligned with the columns of the parent. So I'll have to have responsive sizes that matches the parent sizes. One way could be to add a custom 7-columns grid row for my nested columns. In other words that a nested .col-1 has width: 1/7 (14.28%). What do you think?

Comment: Do you even need nested containers here? Should be somehow possible to keep everything at one level

Comment: Sure it _could_ be possible in this case, but that will not be a good practice in these situations. I'm asking for this particular issue, but also for other similar ones where nesting is needed and we're dealing with odd columns. If there were six columns outside there wouldn't be any issue – we could just go for e.g. 10 columns to make the size of 5 outer columns. **Any one solved this with Bootstrap 4?** This guy _almost_ solved it: https://medium.com/wdstack/the-bootstrap-4-is-getting-odd-e9400b121719

Comment: You can also use negative margins or similar stuff to overlap columns. Always depends on how often the designer is going to overlay the grid over the completed layout.